# Setting ACLs for directories that don't exist (yet)

Tags: setfacl

Can I set ACLs for directories which don't exist yet, but follow a pattern?

I have a directory `/opt/myapp/var` where all sub-directories and files should be owned by `mygroup` and should be group writable.  This is no problem.  During installation of the app, I can do this:

```
prefix=/opt/myapp
chown -R :mygroup $prefix/var                   # All files are owned by mygroup
chmod -R g+w $prefix/var                        # All files group-writable
find $prefix/var -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;  # New files inherit parent's group
find $prefix/var -type d -exec \
      setfacl -dm u::rw,g::rw,o::r {} \;        # New files are 664 instead of 644
```

But my app also works with some profiles which will be created by the app, only after installation. These are in this path:

```
$prefix/home/<profile>/var
```

Is there a way for me to set up ACLs so:

- If `$prefix/home` is ever created, it, and all directories that will be created under it (recursively) are created with `g+s`?
- If `$prefix/home/<profile>/var` is ever created, it and all files that will be created under it (recursively) are created with `g+rw`?

It's tricky because `$prefix/home` doesn't exist yet, and I don't know what the value of `<profile>` when my installation script runs.

Comment: Will `$prefix/home` ever contain any files or directories *other than* those matching your pattern? If not, then you should be able to create `$prefix/home` yourself in the installation script and assign it permissions similar to `$prefix/var`. The sub-directories will inherit the permissions as they are created, and so their sub-subdirectories will inherit them too.